# Difference between %79[^\n] and %79[^\n]\n

Tags: c, scanf, string-formatting

I have two C programs.

First:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    char info[80];
    int started = 0;

    puts("data=[");
    while ((scanf("%f,%f,%79[^\n]",&latitude,&longitude, info)) == 3){
    if (started) 
        printf(",\n");
    else
        started = 1;
    if ((latitude < -90) || (latitude > 90)){
        fprintf(stderr,"Wrong latitude %f\n", latitude);
        return 2;
    }
    if ((longitude < -180) || (longitude > 180)){
        fprintf(stderr,"Wrong longitude %f\n", longitude);
        return 2;
    }

    printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f, info: '%s'}", latitude, longitude, info); 
    }
    puts("\n]");     

    return 0;
}
```

And second:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char line[80];
    FILE *in = fopen("spooky.csv","r");
    FILE *file1 = fopen("ufos.csv","w");    
    FILE *file2 = fopen("disappearances.csv","w");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("others.csv","w");
    while(fscanf(in,"%79[^\n]\n",line)==1){
        if (strstr(line, "UFO"))
            fprintf(file1,"%s\n",line);
        else if (strstr(line, "Disappearance"))
            fprintf(file2, "%s\n", line);
        else 
            fprintf(file3,"%s\n",line);
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why the first code outputs all lines of the my file with instruction `%79[^\n]` and the second code outputs all lines only with this instruction `%79[^\n]\n` and output only one line of text if I write `%79[^\n]`

Please, explain me the differences between two codes and two instructions in them  `%79[^\n]` and `%79[^\n]`

Comment: Iirc `%79[^\n]` should leave the newline in the stream, `%79[^\n]\n` consumes it.

Comment: @Evert yes, you are mistaken.

Comment: Furthermore, if you did think that there *should be one*, then all the programs that you've written that use *scan sets* are broken as well.

Comment: those are not instructions but [format strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Did you read the documentation first?

Comment: @Evert it is explained quite well [in the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12). Note that it is listed *just below* `s` and `c`

Comment: I think you had this program from Head first C book. So read it fully first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the format specifier itself that is causing the problem, but how it is used in conjunction with *other* format specifiers.

If you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see that the `"%["` format does not skip leading white-space, while most other formats (like for example `"%f"`) *do*.

When you read the input in the first program, you don't need the `scanf` function to read the ending newline (which is a white-space character) because the next call to `scanf` will cause the `"%f"` format specifier to skip that newline before it attempts to read a floating point value.

For the second program, if you have `"%79[^\n]"` then `fscanf` will read until but not including the first newline. Then in the next iteration of the loop the same format will attempt to read characters until there is a newline, but the very first character in the input *is* a newline so nothing will be actually read.

If you add the trailing newline (any white-space character would work) then the `fscanf` function will skip the newline, so the next call to `fscanf` will read the next line properly. You can accomplish the same thing by using a *leading* space in your format. I.e. instead of `"%79[^\n]\n"` you could have
`" %79[^\n]"`.

With that said, if you want to read lines, then use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. That's what it does, without many of the problems that `scanf` will have.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* whitespace characters not in conversion specifications will discard *any number of any consecutive whitespace characters* in the input. Therefore your `\n` will eat those whitespace characters in the latter.

Now, `%f` *will* discard all preceding whitespace characters until it finds a non-whitespace character, and start the conversion from that one. `%[^\n]` will not discard any characters - it starts conversion from the first character in the input.